# "Inherently independent" distributions

Tags: probability

Given two cdf's $F_1, F_2\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, it is always possible to find two real-valued random variables $X_1, X_2$ such that $X_i$ is distributed according to $F_i$, and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. (At least, I would be shocked to learn this is not the case.)

I am wondering if there are (nontrivial) instances where this is the "only possibility."

**Question**: Do there exists two cdf's $F_1, F_2\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:

- neither $F_i$ is the distribution of a deterministic random variable;
- for any $X_1,X_2$ such that $X_i$ is distributed according to $F_i$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F$ is a cdf let $G$ be the  "inverse" $G(u):=\inf\{x: F(x)> u\}$. If $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ then the cdf of  $G(U)$   is $F$. So $Y_i:=G_i(U)$ will have cdf $F_i$ (for $i=1,2$) but $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ won't be independent outside of degenerate cases that you have outlawed. The idea is to simulate both cdfs using the same randomness $U$.